# Invalid column name 'is_memory_optimized' in ASP.NET Internet Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I've made an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012 and I haven't made any modifications to it. When I run it and click on login, it generates the tables for the default database. So far so good... However, when I try to view these, I get the following error:

> Failed to retrieve data for this request. An exception occurred while
>   executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. Invalid column name
>   'is_memory_optimized'.

Does anyone have any ideas why a template project does not work?

Comment: Did you play around with the SQL Server 2014 CTP? `is_memory_optimized` is a new feature.

Comment: I did, but not much. I removed the 2014 version and installed 2012 version instead. Maybe there's something to reinstall in VS..

Comment: Looks like you got wrong SMO versions somewhere. Look at all vesions of Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll on your disk and make sure they are at most of version 11. Version 12 should be SQL14, poisoning your machine. Maybe it is easiest to reinstall VS.

Comment: Checked the install locations and the highest version I have is 11. I'll see if a reinstall helps, even if it's annoying to do so.

Comment: Reinstalled VS and tested with a new project, still no luck :/

Comment: Time for blunt measures: install WinGrep and search the entire drive C: for the case-sensitive string "is_memory_optimized". Include binary files (up to 100MB). I suspect that this will show you a location that you did not yet check.

Comment: Unfortunately, the program tends to freeze searching medium to large folders >_< I guess I'll try to work my way around this inconvenience.
EDIT: I just found that I can view my databases in SQL Server Object Explorer view. No clue why Server Explorer view is still not working, but using the other view at least makes it possible to see the data and schemas, so it's at least a workaround.

Comment: You can limit the max file size in the tool. You can also try limiting to *.dll because that will tell you which product is using SQL14 features. You could also look into the programs and features applet to see if something is left there.